# Why does my server crash?

Tags: ssh, crash, headless, minecraft

I use SSH to remotely access a computer (running Ubuntu Server) that I use to host a Minecraft server. For some reason, when I run `start.sh`, which is supposed to start my Minecraft server, my SSH session is disconnected and I have to physically reboot my server to fix it. This is the code of `start.sh`:

```
screen -mdS mcserver
screen -S mcserver -p 0 -X stuff "java -Xmx12G -jar server.jar^M"
```

The server has 16GB of RAM, so that's not the issue.

Edit: The problem also happens when I run the code manually. It disconnects when I run `screen -S mcserver -p 0 -X stuff "java -Xmx12G -jar server.jar^M"`.

Comment: How do you know it's `screen` that crashes your server and not `java`? Have you looked at logs?

Comment: I don't know which one crashes my server, but I will look at the logs. Once I reboot the server again.

Comment: Have you tried the java command without screen? What happened? Also note that the ^M is a carriage return, it probably got there from a Microsoft's Windows machine.

Comment: `^M` is required to press Enter on the screen. It's there intentionally. My server isn't booting now for some reason.

Comment: "to press enter on the screen"? Why would that be necessary?

Comment: It acts as "Enter", otherwise the code would just put `java -Xmx12G -jar server.jar` in the screen session without starting the server.

Comment: If you truly have to press "enter," consider using "expect" to do this. "expect" is a well-known Linux program that's typically installed by default (at least on RHEL systems).